# Python regex to return characters after a search term

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to use regex to extract information from some strings

I can find the text using `re.search`, but how to get the information provided after the search term?

In the format `Ref number ABC123456Ref date 01.01.2000` how can I return `ABC123456` and `01.01.2000`?

```py
import re
reqd_info = "Ref number"
test_text = 'Ref number ABC123456Ref date 01.01.2000'
res = re.search(reqd_info, test_text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groups in your regular expression, then use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get a list of tuples containing the matched groups.

```py
In [1]: import re

In [2]: test_text = 'Ref number ABC123456Ref date 01.01.2000'

In [3]: re.findall("Ref number (.*)Ref date (.*)", test_text)
Out[3]: [('ABC123456', '01.01.2000')]

In [4]: [[number, date]] = re.findall("Ref number (.*)Ref date (.*)", test_text)

In [5]: number
Out[5]: 'ABC123456'

In [6]: date
Out[6]: '01.01.2000'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by changing your regular expresssion to

```regex
<YOUR SEARCHTERM>(.*)
```

this way the result has a group which contains the left over information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `regex`, but it can be done without, too:

```py
test_text = 'Ref number ABC123456Ref date 01.01.2000'
reqd_info = "Ref number"

text = test_text.replace(reqd_info, "").strip() # get rid of Ref number and strip leading and trailing spaces
ref_number, _, date = text.split(" ") # split at spaces

print(ref_number, date)
```

Output:

```py
ABC123456Ref 01.01.2000
```

The above code can be reduced to one line, if you want short code:

```py
test_text = 'Ref number ABC123456Ref date 01.01.2000'
reqd_info = "Ref number"

print(*test_text.replace(reqd_info, "").strip().split(" ")[::2])
```